# what is the size in bytes of iterator in STL in c++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I want to know the size of the iterator (generalization of pointers). More info needed [what is the type of an iterator in STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364050/what-is-the-type-of-an-iterator-in-stl)

Comment: You can easily check that using `sizeof()`?

Comment: The `sizeof` an iterator is basically meaningless.  Why do you need this?

Comment: Why does it matter? Why do you want to know?

Comment: Many iterators in the standard library are the same size as a pointer. Some might be slightly larger.

Comment: @user0042 Thanks.  I was using vector of user defined datatype and i have to sort that user defined based on criteria. I need this to measure the performance and how much memory my program is consuming.So i asked.

Answer (score 6):

There are many different types that can be iterators and each type has a size of their own. The standard does not mandate any limit on such types in general, and not on the size of iterators defined by the standard library in specific.

If you need to know the size of a particular iterator type, that can be observed with the `sizeof` operator, just like with any other type.